# Prove that $3^{1004}+2^{2009}-3^{502}\cdot 2^{1005}\gt 2009^{182}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that $3^{1004}+2^{2009}-3^{502}\cdot 2^{1005}\gt 2009^{182}$.

My try:

we have $$2^{11}\gt 2009$$

Taking power of $182$ both sides we get

$$2^{2002} \gt 2009^{182}$$

Now

$$\left(3^{1004}\right)+\left(2^{2009}\right)-\left(3^{502}\right)\left(2^{1005}\right)=2^{2002}+(127)2^{2002}+\left(3^{1004}\right)-\left(3^{502}\right)\left(2^{1005}\right)=2^{2002}+A$$

Now it suffices to prove $$A \gt 0$$ where

$$A=(127)2^{2002}+\left(3^{1004}\right)-\left(3^{502}\right)\left(2^{1005}\right)$$

any hint?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but the L.H.S. almost equals a binom. To be exact $(3^{502}-2^{1005})^2=3^{1004}+2^{2010}-2\cdot 3^{502}2^{1005}$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-9scNP5KWk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\begin{align}
3^{1004}+2^{2009}-3^{502}\cdot 2^{1005} &= 3^{1004}+2^{2008}-3^{502}\cdot 2^{1005} +2^{2008}\\
&= (2^{1004}-3^{502})^2 +2^{2008}\\
&\gt 2^{2008}\\
&\gt 2009^{182} & \small\text{(per the OP argument)}\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Crystal clear solution, thanks

Comment: Why is it intuitively obvious that $2^{2008} > 2009^{182}$?

Comment: @fleablood Note that $2^{2008}=(2^{11})^{\frac{2008}{11}}=(2048)^{186.545454...}>(2048)^{186}>(2009)^{186}$.

Comment: Also the OP's post already mentions that $2^{2002} > 2009^{182}$

Comment: Yeah.... sure.... It just... I dunno.... as a problem it lack elegance.  I mean.... what's the *point*? "Also the OP's post already mentions that 22002>2009182 "  Oh, why so it does.  Question withdrawn.

Comment: @fleablood I'm sure we've had this question before now I think about it, but answers were approximating the powers of $3$ which actually isn't needed.

Comment: Your answer is very clever.  It just feels like there's a very elegant set up to get the quadratic that's beautiful and perfect... and then we take out a sledge-hammer and smash a cockroach.  Which is undeniably effective but....

Comment: @fleablood approximation questions often feel a bit disappointing if they're not "close enough" to make it interesting. It's sometimes a useful lesson in how bigger powers can be MUCH bigger even than slightly smaller powers - subtract off a lesser power and it has almost no effect.